# Odoo V11 - Sobrescrever informações de um determinado campo no banco

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um filtro para localizar a id de um registro, e a partir daí fazer o update de determinados campos... estou conseguindo localizara os registros mais não estou conseguindo sobrescrever as informações.

```
        if validar_voo:
            logger.info("Entrei aki")
            logger.info(validar_voo[0].nom_localidade)
            voos_dict = {}
            if validar_voo[0].nom_localidade != voo.NOM_LOCALIDADE:
                logger.info(voos_dict)
                voos_dict['nom_localidade'] = voo.NOM_LOCALIDADE
            if validar_voo[0].hor_conf != voo.HOR_CONF:
                voos_dict['hor_conf'] = voo.HOR_CONF
            if validar_voo[0].dsc_equipamento != voo.DSC_EQUIPAMENTO:
                voos_dict['dsc_equipamento'] = voo.DSC_EQUIPAMENTO
            if validar_voo[0].dsc_status != voo.DSC_STATUS:
                voos_dict['dsc_status'] = voo.DSC_STATUS
            if voos_dict != {}:
                logger.info(validar_voo)
                voos = consulta_partidas.write(voos_dict)
```

[Código Completo](https://gist.github.com/thiago95macedo/fb2d846c274541e869cef7b14152d72b)

Answer (score 0):

Erro bobo de lógica

errado:  **voos = consulta_partidas.write(voos_dict)**
correto: **voos = validar_voo.write(voos_dict)**